# Meaning of "fin" in "fin dai tempi"

Tags: word-meaning

I have read the following sentence in https://www.wordreference.com/iten/conoscere:

> Conosco Sergio fin dai tempi dell'università.

It is translated as "I've known Sergio since we were in university", but I don't understand how. Is "fin" a reduced version of "fino" or "fine"? "Fino" is "until" and "fine" is end, so I am lost. Maybe "fino/fine dai tempi" is a fixed expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, here it is a truncated form of *fino*. And *fino* doesn't mean necessarily “until” but rather designates, or highlights, an initial or final endpoint of something. See [Treccani's entry](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fino2) or, in the words of [De Mauro's dictionary](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/fino_2),<sup>1</sup>

> seguito da preposizione o avverbio, indica il limite al quale si arriva o dal quale si parte

*Fin dai tempi (di qualcosa)* is something of a standard phrase, but you can use *fin(o)* in this sense in any number of other phrases: *fin dal Medioevo*, *fin da quando ci siamo conosciuti*, *fin da ora*, the inelegant expression [*fin da subito*](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/proposito-delluso-locuzione-fin-subito) and so on.

Notice that in several cases, and in all of the above examples, *fin(o)* isn't strictly necessary, but stresses the extension back in time of the time period we are talking about. *Fin dal Medioevo* is more or less “since the Middle Age” and “already in the Middle Age” rolled in one.

And one would say *Ti amo fin dal primo momento in cui ti ho vista* to highlight the fact that not even a minute elapsed from the first sighting and the falling in love.

<sup>1</sup> Since the OP has shown to prefer it to other dictionaries.

Comment: Unfortunately, De Mauro's has not examples of this usage of departure point. In Treccani, as my example sentences, "fin" and "da" are always used together in this context. Doesn't "da" already imply a departure point? "fin" seems redundant to me. Don't "Conosco Sergio dai tempi dell'università" and "Conosco Sergio fin dai tempi dell'università" mean the same?

Comment: This what I referred to, fleetingly, by “highlights”. Let me slightly expand my answer.

Comment: So, in Sergio's example, adding _fin_ stresses that you and Sergio go way back.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: I forgot: in other contexts, less usually, _fin_ may well be a truncation for _fine_ too: _in fin dei conti_ or _alla fin fine_, for instance.